# Rendering form manually

Tags: forms

When making my ticket-system I want managers to be able to reply to tickets when viewing the ticket. On the page to view any ticket I load my form. Because I want it to be a bit more fancier than just the default 'element under element' style *I render each item by item manually*.

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['open']); ?>
```

**Now the problem is, my form doens't work. Clicking on my rendered submit doesn't perform any action.**

My guess is that rendering each item manually doesn't include the 'form container'. How should I include is? Or is my style of working completely wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to implement custom rendering of a form would be to use a custom theme hook for the form:

```
/**
 * Builder function for the ticket form.
 */ 
function MODULE_ticket_form($form, $form_state) {
  // Build the $form array here...

  // Let the theme API knows that this form use it own theme hook.
  $form['#theme'] = 'ticket_form';
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    // Custom theme hook for the ticket form.
    'ticket_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Default implementation for the ticket_form theme hook. 
 */
function theme_ticket_form($variables) {
  $form =& $variables['form'];

  //Custom rendering of forms elements goes here...
  $output = ...;    

  // Render every other elements (incl. hidden system ones).
  $output .= drupal_render_children($form);
  return $output;
}
```

Instead of using only a theme function, you can also use a template file. The theme function can also return a [render array](https://drupal.org/node/930760) instead of a string.

Answer (score -1):

Try following will work:

```
<?php $form = drupal_get_form('yourform_id'); ?>

<?php print '<form id="'.$form['#id'].'" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="'.$form['#method'].'" action="'.$form['#action'].'">'; ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['form_id']);?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['form_token']);?>
<?php print '</form>'; ?>
```