# Theming of Entity registration form

Tags: theming, users, display-suite

I'm using [entity registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module on a drupal 7 for events. I managed to enable the registration but I can't find out how to style the registration form.

I tried to modify the form via css but I would prefer have a better control over it, in a template page for example.
I'm quite new to drupal so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's a pretty similar question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33759/rendering-form-manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) to arrange elements and css to style elements. You can create your own template layout in display suite if you need it.